# Xcode 6.1.1 Indexing Forever on a Brand new project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, indexing

I just created a new Project (with no pod files) in Xcode and it stuck on indexing (the spinning loading indicator). I have not added any code in it yet or added anything to the storyboards. I opened some of my older projects and the same thing is happening to those as well. Note that this only happens to my swift projects and not the obj-c ones. I tried cleaning the derived data but nothing happens and problem still exists. I also tried to update the pod files from my older projects but nothing really changes. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downloading Xcode 6.3 Beta but I don't think that, that should be the right solution. Feel free to comment on this..

Comment: You should probably fix 6.1.1 or the last stable release. Not sure if you can submit apps through Beta releases